# the method from descartes' Rules for guiding one's intelligence rule 4

Tags: descartes

the method from descartes' Rules for guiding one's intelligence rule 4.

I can't find the method what he explained.
Would someone tell me what is the method what he explained?

does he explained the method? or just said that the method need to be blah blah?

Do I must find the method by myself? or Descartes already found for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the "traces" of Descartes' (unattained) project in the [Regulae ad directionem ingenii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_for_the_Direction_of_the_Mind) of an "universally applicable" method for the discovery of truth can be found in the three scientific works published with the [Discours de la méthode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_on_the_Method).

In particular, in [La Géométrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie) we can find what remains of the project of a [Mathesis universalis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathesis_universalis).

You can see  : Chikara Sasaki, [Descartes's Mathematical Thought](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402017464) (2003), **Ch.4 : The Mathematical Background of the** *Regulae*, page 159-on.

---

At least, Descartes claimed to have found "the method" for himself ... but he was quite reticent about it.

He gives us "specimens" of it : we have to judge from them about its "soundness".

For sure, Descartes' promise, if any, of a sort of "systematic procedure" (an algorithm, in modern sense) for discovering the truth has been fulfilled only in a limited way by modern science.